# Mouse event messed up by elements behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am overriding the Template for a GroupBox header like this:

```
  <Style x:Key="styleScoreComp" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                    <Composer:AddElementButton Type="Composite"/>
                                    <Composer:AddElementButton Type="Calculation"/>
                                    <Composer:AddElementButton Type="SimulationValue"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>    
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

AddElementButton

```
<Border x:Name="borderButton" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Silver" CornerRadius="4" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5"  Background="White" Width="50" Height="45"  MouseEnter="Border_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Border_MouseLeave"  MouseLeftButtonUp="borderButton_MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image x:Name="imgType" Source="{Binding TypeImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                   Cursor="Hand" Stretch="Uniform"  Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="13"    />                
            <Image Canvas.Top="30" Canvas.Left="7" Source="add.png" Cursor="Hand" Stretch="Uniform"  Width="36" Height="9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   />                
        </Canvas>       
    </Border>
```

Basically, it works, but when you mouse over the middle of the button, it thinks the mouse has left the Border control.  It seems like its happening when the mouse is over where the GroupBox border is.  See this picture:

[image]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem is the order that the groupbox border is being drawn.  I found a site that describes the problem:  http://wpf-mettyz.blogspot.com/2011/02/sample-posting.html

I fixed it by setting the GroupBox style to the following:

```
>  <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}" x:Key="styleTest">
>                 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5"/>
>                 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
>                 <Setter Property="Template">
>                     <Setter.Value>
>                         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
>                             <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
>                                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
>                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
>                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
>                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
>                                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                                     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
>                                     <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
>                                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                                 <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Silver"
>                                         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="4"
> Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>   
> 
>                                 <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
> SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
> Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"/>                    
> 
>                                 <Border x:Name="Header" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
>                                     <ContentPresenter DataContext="{Binding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding
> SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header"
> RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
>                                 </Border>
>                             </Grid>
>                         </ControlTemplate>
>                     </Setter.Value>
>                 </Setter>
>             </Style>
```

and then setting the header to contains the buttons.